# background of game app using javascript and HTML5 canvas

Tags: html

I am creating a gaming application . I have to constantly update the background usig

```
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

But I want to have moving film in background like landscapes mountains , roads , trees passing by )  . How Should I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a video running in the background layer ( refer to video element of html5) and then use the destination-out and source-over property in your canvas . Find code below

```
// Fill canvas using 'destination-out' and alpha at 0.05
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0,W,H);
ctx.fill();
// Set the default mode.
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

This way your background will be running independent of the game . Ofcourse you can pause and resume it using eventlistners etc in javascript